A probabilistic optimization problem on machine diversity
I have a quota of $n$ machines for a test that exposes issues in machines.
Each machine can be of one of the types: $1, 2, \dots k$. So, I need to allocate $n_1$ machines of type-1, $n_2$ machines of type-2 and so on where $n_1+n_2+\dots +n_k = n$
A machine of type $j$ has a hidden issue unique to that machine type. In the test, each machine of type $j$ will have a (given) probability, $p_j$ that the issue will manifest in the test and $(1-p_j)$ that it won't manifest and the test will run smoothly.
To flag an issue (of any type $j$) in the test, I have to see $3$ or more machines manifesting it. I need to maximize the total issues I flag. What I can control are the $n_1, n_2, \dots n_k$. How do I find the optimal $n_1, n_2, \dots n_k$ that will maximize the expected number of issues I flag?

My attempt
If we take indicator random variables for each machine type indicating whether nor not the issue was raised in the test, the number of issues raised will be a sum of the indicator random variables for each machine type. The expected number of issues will be the sum of probabilities across the machine types. The random variable defining the number of issues raised for machine $j$ is binomial with parameters $n_j$ and $p_j$ (here $n_j$ is set by us). And the probability an issue is raised becomes the probability that the random variable is greater than or equal to $3$. So, the expected number of issues raised becomes:
$$E = \sum\limits_{j=1}^k\sum\limits_{i=3}^{n_j} {n_j \choose i}(p_j)^i(1-p_j)^{n_j-i}$$
We need to find the non-negative integers, $n_1, n_2 \dots n_k$ that maximize $E$ while satisfying $n_1+n_2+\dots n_k = n$.
One way is to brute force enumerate all possible combinations of $n_1, n_2, \dots n_k$ and calculate $E$ for all of them, finally selecting the best one. But this algorithm has poor scaling characteristics since the number of possible combinations is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$ (stars and bars). Is there a more efficient exact algorithm? Or is this problem NP-hard and we have to be satisfied with a heuristic?

Can we start from small $k$ values?

Yeah sure. Can even simplify and say 1 failure is enough to detect the issue instead of 3.

Intuitively, when $n$ is large and all $p_i$'s are equal, we want to evenly distribute the machines. But I am not sure what should be the "weights" when $p_i$'s are differnet.

When $n$ (and each $n_i$) is large, the change on each $i$ when increasing/decreasing $n_i$ by $1$ would be approximately $\frac{{n_i}^2 (1-p_i)^{n_i} {p_i}^3}{2}$, so we might want to balance ${n_i}^2 (1-p_i)^{n_i} {p_i}^3$ for different $i$'s.

You can linearize the problem as follows.  For $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ and $m\in\{0,\dots,n\}$, let binary decision variable $x_{jm}$ indicate whether $n_j=m$.  The problem is to maximize
$$\sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\sum_{i=3}^m \binom{m}{i} p_j^i (1-p_j)^{m-i}\right) x_{jm} \tag1\label1$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^n x_{jm} &= 1 &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$} \tag2\label2\\
\sum_{m=0}^n m x_{jm} &= n_j &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$} \tag3\label3\\
\sum_{j=1}^k n_j &= n \tag4\label4
\end{align}
The parenthesized expression in \eqref{1} does not depend on decision variables, and hence \eqref{1} is a linear function of $x$.  Constraints \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} enforce $x_{jm}=1 \iff n_j=m$.  Constraint \eqref{4} allocates all $n$ machines.
Now call an integer linear programming solver.
